# Nginx removes Content-Length header when acting as reverse proxy behind a WAF

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy, artifactory, web-application-firewall

I have Nginx 1.16.1 as a reverse proxy for JFrog Artifactory and they are reachable from the external networks via web application firewall. I am trying to get `docker` client working with this setup. It sends a `HEAD` request and awaits a `Content-Length` to [check for the existence](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#pushing-an-image) of a layer. Now I see that `Content-Length` is not included in the response received by the client. I can examine it by sending the same request using `curl` that sends `docker`:

```
$ curl -H 'User-Agent: docker/19.03.13 go/go1.13.15 git-commit/4484c46d9d kernel/4.19.128-microsoft-standard os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.13 \(linux\))' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  -H 'Connection: close' \
  -I \
   "https://${ARTIFACTORY_URL}/v2/${IMAGE}/blobs/${DIGEST}"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2020 14:57:05 GMT
Server: Secure Entry Server
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Docker-Content-Digest: sha256:[MASKED]
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
X-Artifactory-Id: [MASKED]
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: [MASKED]
Set-Cookie: SCDID_S=[MASKED]; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Connection: close
```

However, I see in the access log of Artifactory that it sets this response header. I used `tcpdump` to see what data is exchanged between Nginx and Artifactory:

```
HEAD /v2/[MASKED]/blobs/[MASKED] HTTP/1.1
X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url: https://[MASKED]:443
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Host: [MASKED]
X-Forwarded-For: 10.10.40.14
Connection: close
ClientCorrelator: 0rIKeSpqZ9E$
RequestCorrelator: 7f0100-9099-2020.11.09_1457.05.275-001
HSP_CLIENT_ADDR: [MASKED]
Hsp-ListenerUri: https://[MASKED]
HSP_HTTPS_HOST: [MASKED]:443
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer [MASKED]
User-Agent: docker/19.03.13 go/go1.13.15 git-commit/4484c46d9d kernel/4.19.128-microsoft-standard os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/19.03.13 \(linux\))
HTTPS: on
SSLSessionID: 78ad360e9ea54f5efdb72ea223a63b6cbc7788ae9a1e876620e398040d06182c
SSLSessionTimeLeft: 3600
SSLSessionAge: 0
SSLCipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
SSLCipherKeySize: 128
SSLProtocolVersion: TLSv1.2
Via: HTTP/1.1 Secure Entry Server

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 2529
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2020 14:57:05 GMT
Docker-Content-Digest: [MASKED]
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Server: Artifactory/7.4.1 70401900
X-Artifactory-Id: 5a2dee84b6d80d2f:1f521881:17554c79de4:-8000
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: [MASKED]
Connection: close
```

The TrafficAnalyzer on the WAF shows that `Content-Length` in the incoming response from Artifactory is missing. Hence it must be Nginx responsible for removing it.

Now when I connect via VPN to get around the WAF the response looks okay:

```
Host:           [MASKED]
User-Agent:     docker/19.03.13 go/go1.13.15 ...
Authorization:  Bearer [MASKED]
Connection:     close

Date:                           Fri, 06 Nov 2020 17:13:58 GMT
Content-Type:                   application/octet-stream
Content-Length:                 2529
Docker-Content-Digest:          [MASKED]
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version:registry/2.0
Server:                         Artifactory/7.4.1 70401900
X-Artifactory-Id:               5a2dee84b6d80d2f:1f521881:17554c79de4:-8000
X-Artifactory-Node-Id:          [MASKED]
Connection:                     close
```

But I also notice, that there are fewer headers set in the request. Is that some additional WAF-header that causes Nginx to remove `Content-Length`? I don't see anything related to this in Nginx debug log. Any thoughts?

Comment: which WAF is your organization using? it is possible that the WAF is removing the content-length header (for example if the response is chunked or compressed)

Comment: Hello Dror, the header is missing in the incoming response on the WAF, before any processing applies. Also, you see that the response is neither chunked nor compressed since it's just an answer to a `HEAD` request.